# Including original text format

Tags: php, mysql, html

I would like for posts returned from my database, from users, to be formatted the same way they originally input them.

Like when I echo out the text from a row of data it comes out like this:

```
Hello There.
```

When the user originally formatted it like this:

```
Hello
There.
```

Notice the return? How do I achieve this?

Here is my html:

```
        <form method="post" action="share.php">
            <textarea name="story"></textarea>
            <div id="share-something-bottom">
                <div id="share-something-camera">
                    <img src="images/camera.png"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="share"    
                                           name="share"><p>Share</p></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I am using a varchar field in my database table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store the formatting in the DB and make sure you escape it before storing it.

Comment: You write it to the DB an make sure no nasty escape sequence get added by using things like http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php. Not that if it was just a textarea it is probably easier to display the data back there or use <pre> tags

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to preserve newlines when you echo them on the page, you need to use `nl2br()`.

```
echo nl2br($string_from_database);
```

You could also wrap the string in `<pre>` tag, but that will also affect the used font (by default).